# android studio can't resolve adView class

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to integrate admob rewarded video ads.I got blank project.Also I have integrated firebase sdk according to [this spec](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).However when I type `AdView` class android studio doesn't see it.Package `com.google.android.gms.ads` doesn't contain ad classes like `AdRequest` or `MobileAds`.My gradle files:

root:

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
   }

   allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.rhyboo.net.rewarded_video"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed the last step from the guide, which is to add the libraries for Firebase and the individual services you're using.

Just add these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
```

to your build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' // new!
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'  // new!
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

That's the proper way to import AdMob with Firebase. You can check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qCxo0D-Sak&index=6&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKX0pUJV3uqp6N3NeHwHh0c) for a walkthrough.

Comment: damn,I was sure I have these dependencies.Now I have `I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful` note in the console.And I don't need to import google play services anymore.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

forgot to add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'` into app-level dependencies block

Comment: That gets you Google Play services, which isn't the same thing as Firebase. It also contains the Mobile Ads SDK, though, which has the AdView class.